# How to check command arguments in main class java

Tags: java, command-line

i've got the following program: i have a jar file which is getting 4 parameteres from main method :input file,order by, sort direction, output file. The input file is the file where information will be read , order by is sorting by (test,runs , etc), sort direction (asc, desc) and outputfile where information will be saved. Here is my code in main method :

```
      if (args.length > 0)
        {
            if (args[0].isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Enter input file");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                args[0] = inputFile;
            }
            if (args[1].isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Enter order by");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                args[1] = orderBy;
            }
            if (args[2].isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Enter sort direction");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                args[2] = sortDirection;
            }
            if (args[3].isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Enter output file");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                args[3] = outputFile;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Must enter parameteres!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

          SaveInfoManager.SaveInFile(inputFile, sortDirection, orderBy, outputFile);
```

And i have a following error: ArraysIndexOutOfBoundsException when i do not enter some argument. Example i do not enter the 3rd argument which is sort direction and i want to print message that is not entered. But i do not understand why is throwing that exception even i make a check. Can you tell me where is my fault and how i can do it properly ?

Comment: The `args` array has the size of the number of provided arguments. You'd better check the size of the array to know how many were provided.

Comment: You checked if `args.length > 0` before accessing _any_ args.  That tells you `args[0]` is within bounds, but that's all.  You can't safely access `args[1]` without checking `args.length > 1`, or `args[2]` without checking `args.length > 2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`args[n].isEmpty()` checks whether the string that is contained in position `n` of the array is empty, which results in `ArraysIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the array has less than `n` elements.
In order to check the length of the array you need to use

```
if(args.length == 4){ ... }
```

Comment: Ok, but how i can check the specific 2nd parameter  for example. And tell the user it must be filled

Comment: @George You could use `if(args.length<2)...` to see if there are less than 2 parameters. Checking if a specific parameter is missing isn't really possible since you only use the order of the arguments to indicate which one is which. If you want to check specific parameters I suggest that you add flags to the arguments.